# How to split newline from char pointer in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, split

I have a buffer, that is `char` pointer. The content of this is something like:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

How can I just get the `aaa` first line from that `char` pointer? 
I try to convert it into NSString first, but can I split it by `\n` in Objective-c?

Something like:

`arrayString[0] = "aaa"`, `arrayString[1] = "bbb"`, `arrayString[2] = "ccc"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  char *buffer = "aaa \n bbb \n ccc \n";
  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
  NSLog(@"arr: %@", arr);
```